# Better strategy to save files in file system?

Tags: java, file-io, content-management-system

I'm trying to create a discussion board where different users can comment and attach files.
But I want to store those attachments in filesystem instead of database.

I have two ideas to implements the above.

1) Flat file system:- Here i will store all files in the same folder by prefixing discussion id,comment id with hyphen.

2) Hierarchical file system:- here i will create a parent folder with discussion id, and inside discussion id i will create a comment id folder and inside this folder i will add attachments.

but the above are specific to discussion board.

But i want to create a generic file management system to store any type of attachments.
So please help me out finding best solution.

Thanks

Uday.Nalla

Comment: So by saying “ I dont want” you mean “I want”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain file systems have limitations regarding the number of files in a single directory and so have lots of tools. Imagine a simple `rm *` not working because the command line being too long after substitution. Or being unable to scroll in a visual file management tool because a single pixel in the scroll bar is associated with hundreds of files. Even with a hierarchical structure you might run into these problems if your board gets huge. But it’s fairly better to handle.

Of course, that all doesn’t matter as long as your board works and doesn’t need any manual administration. But I would prefer to keep administration in mind. After all, supporting hierarchical structures is a feature of the file system, so let it help you if you have hierarchically structured data.